# Given a max heap represented as an array,return the kth largest element without modifying the heap

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This is a interview question.I am unable to do anything better than klogN.
This is to be done in O(logN) time where N is the size of the heap.

Comment: You are aware that `k log N` *is* `O(log N)`, are you not? A constant multiplicative factor does not change the `O()` complexity of an algorithm...

Comment: @twalberg: k isn't usually assumed to be constant in problems like this, either in theory or practice.